# Equivalent PowerShell FileSystemRights of clicking the Full Control checkbox and then Unchecking it in the Permission Entry Dialog?

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, ntfs

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx) for `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights` enumeration lists NTFS file/folder permission rights that can be applied to an ACE, that will be added to an ACL, with a snippet like the following specifying the rights:

```
$fileOrFolderRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Read, Write"
```

When instructed to do this manually in the `Permission Entry` Dialog, my boss told me to check the `Full Control` checkbox, and then uncheck it.

I want to say that all I need to do to duplicate this is to include all of the members listed in the [FileSystemRights documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx) less the `FullControl` one; but I don't think this is the case, since there are special permissions too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to work this out is probably to replicate the procedure in the gui then use powershell to see what the reported rights are using get-acl. My results are below.

```
PS D:\test> (get-acl test.txt).Access

FileSystemRights  : Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : Everyone
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```